# Inversão de String linguagem C

Tags: c, array, string

Tenho que fazer um programa e quase terminei o mesmo.

Segue o que se pede:

Palíndromo é uma frase ou palavra que mantém o mesmo sentido quando lida de trás pra frente, por exemplo osso, esse, ele, ralar, etc. Faça um programa que leia uma palavra de no máximo 20 caracteres e imprima se esta palavra é um palíndromo ou não.

Esta função deve retornar 1 se a palavra for um palíndromo, ou 0, caso o contrário.

Entrada: Uma string.
Saída: Palíndromo ou Nao e um palindromo.

O problema é que o código inverte a string, porém está faltando algo para consertar e fazer efetivamente a comparação das strings **str** e **teste**

Bibliotecas usadas (`stdio.h`, `stdlib.h` e `string.h`)

```
char str[20],teste[20]; // teste = cópia da str p/ testar condição palíndromo
int a,i,j,tam = 0;
scanf("%s",str);

for (i = 0, j = strlen(str); str[i] !='\0'; i++,j--){
    teste[j-1] = str[i];
    tam++;
}
    teste[j-1] = '\0';

for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
    printf("%c",teste[i]); // imprime normalmente a string invertida na tela
}
printf("\n");

printf("%s\n",teste); // saída da string teste, porém nessa saída é possível ver que há mais caracteres inclusos na string e assim, invalidam a comparação que deverá ser feita.

return 0;
}
```

Este é o trecho final do código a ser posto no lugar do `printf("%s\n",teste);` da penúltima linha.

```
if(strcmp (str, teste) == 0){
    printf("Palindromo");
}else{
    printf("Nao e um palindromo");
}
```

Antecipo meus agradecimentos a quem puder ajudar!

Comment: Este código é confuso, ineficiente e faz coisas que o enunciado não pode. Na pergunta já respondida tem uma forma muito mais simples.

Comment: Opa valeu. Já vi lá o algoritmo usado. Obrigado pela ajuda :)